# How to concatenate two column in talend tMap

Tags: talend

I have two column SalesID (Long 10 digit) and ItemID(Varchar 6) Now I want to concatenate these two column to make a 16 digit.

```
For example-  SalesID = 1234567899
              ItemID  = 32X9

  Desired concatenated value should be:- 12345678990032X9
```

How can I achieve about output through tMap in talend?

Comment: (I like to dig old question...) @Sharad, please remember to accept an answer if it suit your need.

Answer (score 2):

Using Java syntax, you can easily concatenate your input data in the Tmap component:

[image]

Comment: Just saying, but in Java it would be correcly done with `row1.SalesID + String.format("%6s", row1.ItemID).replace(" ", "0")` to get a valid output.

Comment: Yeah maybe, it was just an example to how concatenate in Talend, then he can do it in a better way, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do it using tJavaRow component 
put below logic into it

```
output_row.SALESID = input_row.SALESID;
output_row.ITEMID = input_row.ITEMID;
output_row.ITEMID_ZERO = String.format("%6s",input_row.ITEMID).replace(' ','0');
```

output_row.CONCATENATE = output_row.SALESID+""+output_row.ITEMID_ZERO;